# Ionic Framework + Composer?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, composer-php

I'm working on a project that only has a REST API PHP5 Library and it uses Composer.

I have never touched Composer —but I understand  it is a package manager—and avoid PHP if I can. How can I get something like this into an Ionic project? As far as I know Node and PHP don't like each other very much and I don't see anything online with Composer and Ionic working together?

Is this possible?

Anything out there I should take a look at? or tips, suggestions or documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing several things here. It might help to differentiate between frontend and backend.

Both, AngularJS and Iconic are frontend frameworks.
They often live in the browser or standalone frontend application, which might do requests to a backend to retrieve data for display.

Such a backend might be provided by a PHP application. And this PHP application might use or depend on a third-party library. In the PHP ecosystem dependencies are often fetched with Composer. The application itself needs a `composer.json` file, which contains the requirements for the application. Composer resolved the versions and fetches the dependencies into the local PHP project.

The mentioned PHP "REST API" library might be two things (not enough information provided):

- an API wrapper, which provides access to a certain API

  - e.g. PHP could use the library to fetch something from a specific API, like Google Maps API,  manipulate the result set and return it, as a response to a request from your frontend app
- or a helper library for building a REST application faster with (to provide an API endpoint)

Application-wise the worlds a completely separated. These worlds are only connected via HTTP requests.

Your request goes: Frontend (Iconic/AngularJs) to Backend (PHP) (and maybe internally using the REST lib from PHP to API) and then you get a response (PHP to frontend). That's it.

Not sure, where Node comes into play here. I think of NodeJS more as a server-side tool. So, its possible to replace the PHP backend with a Node backend.
The node ecosystem has other package managers, like npm and on top of that lives bower.

Comment: Great explanation and you're right about where NodeJS fits in, because it doesn't really fit in with PHP, however you can, but there's not really a need to unless you need a PHP library. You can spin up a server with Grunt or Gulp with NodeJS and have it handle Javascript or Apache with PHP. However, turns out I was sent a wrong link. Although dabbling I did figured out that composer.json was the package manager file. Similar to nodeJS package.json and I simply loaded my project with something like `composer composer.json` ...continued in Part2

Comment: Part2 (sorry theres a word count): but now I have the right link and can now just make REST API calls in the NodeJS using the MEAN Stack for backend and have what I think is going to kill PHP as my generation sticks to node and  stay away from the dreadful PHP, but a lot of older companies are stuck on PHP and SQL so who knows. Node is taking off.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.. (All off-topic:) Uh, when i read "my generation sticks to Node" i feel old. :( Most people are fascinated by Node, when starting to work with it, because its JS on frontend and backend side. But at the moment maintenance costs for Node projects are simply too high, because the underlying API of the core and the packages changes to often. There are still many `v0.x.x` versions around in the Node ecosystem, but it will stabilize over time. The big question is: Will time to production be cheaper with Node than with PHP? Maybe in the future.. lets see how that turns out.